# Is there an open set $U$ such that $\mu(U)=\mu(A)$ where $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue measurable. Does there exist an open set $U \supseteq A$ such that $\mu(U)=\mu(A)$? Does there exist a closed set $F \subseteq A$ such that $\mu(F)=\mu(A)$?

Comment: How far have you looked for counterexamples?

Comment: @AnginaSeng I know theorems of the form " A is measurable if and only if ∀ϵ, ∃ open set G and closed set H such that H⊂A⊂G and μ(G|H)<ϵ. But I couldn't figure out how this helps since I want equality.

Comment: What happens if $A=\Bbb Q$ is the set of rational numbers, or $A=\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ is the set of irrational numbers?

Comment: No. No. Take $A=\{0\}$ for the first, $A=(0,1)$ for the second.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of counterexamples.

Take $A$ be any subset of $\mathbb R$ with zero measure. For each non-empty open set $U$ containing $A$, since any open set contains an open interval, we have $\mu(U)>0=\mu(A)$.

Take $A$ be any non-empty open subset of $\mathbb R$ with finite measure. For each closed set $F$ contained in $A$, the set $A\setminus F$ is non-empty and open so $\mu(A\setminus F)>0$, hence $\mu(F)=\mu(A)-\mu(A\setminus F)<\mu(A)$.